# How to get the list inside a resultset?

Tags: java, list, jdbc, arraylist, resultset

I make a query in my database and put the results in a resultset. I have 8 attributes in the resultset, and first 7 of them are strings, so i can take them by writing:

```
rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2) ... etc
```

Then at the index 8, i have an ArrayList. I try to take it and create new list with the values in it but i could not do it. Here is my code, you can see what i tried there in the commented out line:

```
public void loginCheck() {
    try {
        Bank bank = Bank.getBank();
        ResultSet rs = queryDatabase();

        if (rs.next()) {
          //  List<Account> a = (List<Account>) rs.getObject(8, ArrayList);  DOES NOT WORK
            Customer currentCustomer = new Customer(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7));
            addToSession(currentCustomer);
            rs.close();
            DBConnect.disconnect(con);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("main.xhtml");
        } else {
            rs.close();
            DBConnect.disconnect(con);
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
    }
}

private ResultSet queryDatabase() {
    con = DBConnect.connect();
    try {
        PreparedStatement checkDB = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users where identityNumber = ? AND password = ?");
        checkDB.setString(1, identityNumber);
        checkDB.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet res=(ResultSet) checkDB.executeQuery();
        return res;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit: I have a Customer object with 8 attributes, first 7 of them are string and the last one is an ArrayList object. My resultset rs contains a Customer object, so i want to get this list from the resultset, i mean the accounts of this specific user

So how can i get this ArrayList in the resultset? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should count form 0..7 instead of 1..8? It might be helpful to include the unexpected output you're getting btw.

Comment: @eriksensei i think it starts from 1, because index 0 returns null and index 1 returns the first attribute

Comment: Ah, I see, it's a JDBC-ism apparently. So what's the output you're getting?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? What's the error?

Comment: @codingbiz it says cannot find the symbol ArrayList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your commented code you are missing **.class**, it should be:

```
List<Account> a = (List<Account>) rs.getObject(8, ArrayList.class);
```